# How to optimize this for loop function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, lodash

```
var tickers = [];

for (var i=0; i<reportsArray.length; i++) {
    tickers.push(reportsArray[i].ticker);
}
```

Is there a way to replicate the above using the fastest / most efficient way in [lodash](https://lodash.com).

This is what the objects may look like in the `reportsArray`:

```
{
    added_epoch: 1452873186
    details: ""
    reason: ""
    term: "Google rocks!"
    ticker: "GOOG"
    user_id: 1346753
    username: "leon"
}
```

Comment: Nothing in lodash is going to be faster than what you're doing but have you looked into use [`map`](https://lodash.com/docs#map)? There's also [a native implementation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: I agree with @MikeC, but you can verify by creating tests with realistic data on https://jsperf.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is all you need.

```
var tickers = reportsArray.map(function (report) {
    return report.ticker;
});
```

And, if you want to do this in Lodash anyway, use _.map() to achieve the same result.

```
var tickers = _.map(reportsArray, function (report) {
    return report.ticker;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I renamed my title to better fit, also great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use just

```
var tickers = _.map(reportsArray, 'ticker');
```